# RecyclerView как добавить запись при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Хочу создать приложение, в начале будет `EditText`, а рядом `Button (Add)`. Пишешь список продуктов, которые должен купить из магазина и по очереди добавляешь их в список. Хочу это все сделать с помощью `RecyclerView`. Посмотрел в интернете, но там только примеры, как нужно создавать `RecyclerView`, а я хочу нажатием кнопки создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно:

1. Создать разметку с полем ввода, кнопкой и `RecyclerView`
2. Создать переменную-список `List<Product>` куда будете добавлять продукты из поля ввода при нажатии на кнопку
3. При нажатии на кнопку надо добавить `Product` в их список из п.2 и вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged()` метод у адаптера `RecyclerView`
4. Надо создать адаптер из п.3 и сразу, ещё до создания продуктов, прямо в момент создания актвити/фрагмента, присвоить его `RecyclerView`

Т.е. вам нужно написать следующее

1. Класс активити
2. Разметка активити
3. Класс адаптера
4. Разметка элемента списка для адаптера

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Наверное сразу можно сказать, что создавать какой-то `List` в практическом применении несколько бессмысленно, так как данные в нем будут жить, пока существует активити, в которой он создан - в реальном приложении такой подход практически не используется. То есть нужно работать с каким то источником постоянного хранения данных.